# Best strategy to alter sql table / migrate in prod at the same time as your backend

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, migration

I'm currently designing sql tables for a website (I chose PostgreSQL) and I don't have a lot of experience when it comes to updating databases in prod.

In the mean time I'm also coding the backend (in node.js) which relies on this db.

In the future, I'll deploy everything and from time to time, I'll probably have to update my existing tables like renaming a column / a table, or removing a column, etc.

Now I'd like these updates to be completely invisible to the users so I don't want my website to be offline.

Usually my strategy is to have to instances, `b1` and `b2`, behind a load balancer so when you do an update, you update `b1`, restart it and during the restart users are still redirected to `b2` and then you update `b2` while users are redirected to `b1`.

But now, if I just update the db or the backend separately, there would be a mismatch anyway.

For example let say that I have the following table:

```
--------
Account
--------
id: bigint
name: varchar(32)
```

Here if I want to rename `name` to `firstname`, I need to make sure that both backend & database are deployed in production at the same time.

So I could have a deployment script that shutdowns the backend in prod, updates the database (i.e. rename `name` to `firstname`), updates the backend with that change and start the backend again, the tricky part is how to make sure users aren't disconnected during this update.

Some companies manage to do it so it's never noticeable (Google) but not sure what's the best strategy to do it, maybe having 2 databases that you can re-sync after an update?

Answer (score 1):

The strategy for no downtime is something like this

1. Add a column called firstname
2. Start dual writing and updating both name and firstname
3. Run a script to copy name value and update firstname for every row where firstname doesn't have a value (this is essentially a backfill)
4. Now  start reading firstname instead of name
5. Drop name column

Depending on which framework you use, part 2 can be easier by leveraging ORM. For Rails, after commit hooks work really well. Postgresql will also have triggers which you can use too.

Your alternate option is to just take a downtime hit from your availability budget for the app. Renaming a column for a table with less than 10 million rows, will be a few seconds (under a minute for sure) and deploying you're new app right shouldn't take long either if it is only a few instances where the code needs to be deployed. (RECOMMENDED, far less effort)

I'd definitely go for the latter, unless you have a lot more data or can't afford the downtime / 5xx.